# How to handle LemmatizerTrainer 'UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long'?

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp, lemmatization

I am using Opennlp to train a model for lemmatization of german words. Therefore I use the opennlp cli and the training set of [UD_German-HDT](https://github.com/UniversalDependencies/UD_German-HDT/blob/master/README.md) which can be downloaded [here](https://universaldependencies.org/#download)

The training itself works fine (just need a little bit of ram) but the cli fails to write the model because of an `UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long` exception.

The cli command I am using: `opennlp LemmatizerTrainerME.conllu -params params.txt -lang de -model de-lemmatizer.bin -data UD_German-HDT/de_hdt-ud-train.conllu -encoding UTF-8`

Stacktrace:

```
Writing lemmatizer model ... failed
Error during writing model file 'de-lemmatizer.bin'
encoded string too long: 383769 bytes
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 383769 bytes
        at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:364)
        at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
        at opennlp.tools.ml.maxent.io.BinaryGISModelWriter.writeUTF(BinaryGISModelWriter.java:71)
        at opennlp.tools.ml.maxent.io.GISModelWriter.persist(GISModelWriter.java:97)
        at opennlp.tools.ml.model.GenericModelWriter.persist(GenericModelWriter.java:75)
        at opennlp.tools.util.model.ModelUtil.writeModel(ModelUtil.java:71)
        at opennlp.tools.util.model.GenericModelSerializer.serialize(GenericModelSerializer.java:36)
        at opennlp.tools.util.model.GenericModelSerializer.serialize(GenericModelSerializer.java:29)
        at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.serialize(BaseModel.java:597)
        at opennlp.tools.cmdline.CmdLineUtil.writeModel(CmdLineUtil.java:182)
        at opennlp.tools.cmdline.lemmatizer.LemmatizerTrainerTool.run(LemmatizerTrainerTool.java:77)
        at opennlp.tools.cmdline.CLI.main(CLI.java:256)
```

Has somebody encountered this problem and has a solution?

Comment: I do have exactly the same task and the same problem, as written above. I feel you.

Comment: Dropped a mail on dev@opennlp.a.o -> https://lists.apache.org/thread/vc5lfzj81tco703noqxpvy8sfj8fw8b1

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENNLP-1366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, I've written a patch to cure [OpenNLP-1366](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENNLP-1366). The related PR https://github.com/apache/opennlp/pull/427 documents the problem and solution in detail.

In this context, the upcoming OpenNLP version **2.0.1** will bring the cure for the problem reported in the OP. Updating to the aforementioned version will resolve the crashing during writing trained model files.

*Note:* 
I verified that the patch works with `UD_German-HDT`, `UD_German-GSD`, and other treebanks for the German language.